# Viewing limit as a map

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

**Question:**  Let $X$ be a set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.  Consider the subset $X_0$ of the sequences $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ for which
$$
f_{\infty}(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x),
$$
is a well-defined function.  Is there any literature studying the continuity of the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Lim}: X_0 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}\\
(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} & \to f(\cdot):= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(\cdot)?
\end{aligned}
$$

*My question is in some sense motivated by the following problem:*

**Motivation:**
For each $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ let $f_{n,k},f_{k}\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and suppose that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_k$ is the uniform on compacts limit of $f_{n,k}$. Suppose also that there is a Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x)= \lim\limits_{k \to \infty}f_k\circ \dots \circ f_1(x)$.

Then, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, does

$$
\lim\limits_{(n,k)\to \infty}f_{n,k}\circ \dots \circ f_{n,1}(x) = f(x)?
$$

In other words: when does $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\operatorname{Lim}((f_{n,k})_{k})=\operatorname{Lim}(f_{k})$?

Comment: To give an example for **Motivation**: Let's build $f_{n,k}(x)$ such that it is equal to the identity outside of $[n+k-2, n+k]$, and it is linear on $[n+k-2, n+k-3/2]$ and on $[n+k-1/2,n+k]$, with $f_{n,k}(x) = n+k+1$ on the segment $[n+k-3/2,n+k-1/2]$. Clearly $f_{n,k}$ are continuous. For fixed $k$, $f_{n,k}$ converges uniformly on compacts to $x\mapsto x$. And so we have $f_k(x) = f(x) = x$. However given $n$ fixed, $f_{n,k} \circ \cdots f_{n,1}(x) = n+k + 1$ for every $x\in [n-1/2, n+1/2]$. So we don't have a limiting function $\mathrm{Lim}((f_{n,k})_k)$.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this more: if you let your functions to be constant functions, your question immediately reduce to the one about "when do limits commute for double sequences". So I think the fact that $f_*$ are functions are really a bit of a red herring here.

Comment: @WillieWong You're right I didn't think of that.  In that case, do you know of a generalization of the moore-osgood theorem for function spaces?  That would do the trick..

Comment: Moore-Osgood works for [general metric spaces](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moore-Osgood_Theorem). Using the notation of that link: let $Y$ be your desired function space (for example the space of bounded continuous functions with the $\sup$ norm), and let $X$ be either $\mathbb{N}$ (and you have to modify the theorem appropriately), or $\mathbb{R}$ (and use $1/n$ instead of $n$).

Comment: Interesting, then is it at-least possible to find a convergence subsequence after swapping the limits?